# Firestore pre-deployment script

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm searching for a way to add pre-deployment scripts to my Firebase project.
I'm using Firestore and my security rules are set up in a way that only cloud functions can write to Firestore.

I've added a user role field to my user table which automatically gets populated on userCreate. This works fine but my prod env still has users without this field.
A logical solution would be to run a pre-deploy command which add this field to all existing users but I have no clue how to do this.

My current best solution is to create a cloud function specifically for this one-time use and trigger it.
This doesn't feel like the right way to handle such things.
How do I run a one time update statement on Firestore?

Comment: Hello @Jonathan, is the issue resolved? Please feel free to ask any subsequent questions. You can also accept the answer by clicking on tick icon so others know it is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a temporary script using Firebase Admin SDK and execute it once. The flow would look something like:

1. Fetching all documents without the userRole field.
2. Add update statements in an array and execute all the promises at once.

Here's a demo:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const serviceAccount = require("/path/to/serviceAccountKet.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://fate-bot-discord.firebaseio.com"
});

async function addRoles() {
    try {
        const userColRef = admin.firestore().collection("users")
        const users = await userColRef.where("userRole", "==", "").get()
        const updates = []

        users.docs.forEach((user) => {
            updates.push(userColRef.doc(user.id).update({ userRole: "theNewRole" }))
        })
        await Promise.all(updates)
        console.log("Roles added successfully")
        return "Roles Added"
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return error
    }
}

//Call the function
addRoles().then((response) => {
  console.log(response)
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log(e)
})
```

Please let me know if you need further assistance!

Comment: I'm quite the noob if it comes to Node. How do I resolve `firebase-admin` running this as a one time script from Node?

Comment: @Jonathan sure. Create a new file for example, onetime.js. Paste the code above. Do necessary changes such as collection ID and field name and roles that you have mentioned. Then open terminal/CMD and run `node ontime.js`, the file should execute once.

Comment: It says `Error: Cannot find module 'firebase-admin'`, I installed firebase-admin globally

Comment: @Jonathan please follow these commands and try again: 1. Create a new folder 2. Inside of it use, `npm init` and set it up. 3. npm i firebase-admin (not global) 4. onetime.js... Also make sure you have used the correct path to the service Account key

Answer (score 0):

I've updated @Dharmaraj answer with some extra features in case someone ever needs this.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
// DEV
const serviceAccount = require('./x-dev-firebase-adminsdk-1234.json');
// PROD
// const serviceAccount = require('./x-firebase-adminsdk-1234.json');
const newRoles = [0];
const emails = ['admin1@gmail.com', 'admin2@gmail.com'];

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

const addRoles = async () => {
  try {
    let userColRef = admin.firestore().collection('users');
    if (emails.length) {
      userColRef = userColRef.where('email', 'in', emails);
    }

    const users = await userColRef.get();

    const updates = [];

    users.docs.forEach((doc) => {
      const user = doc.data();
      let existingRoles = [];
      if (user.roles) {
        existingRoles = user.roles;

        if (newRoles.every((role) => existingRoles.includes(role))) {
          return;
        }
      }

      const roles = Array.from(new Set(existingRoles.concat(newRoles)));

      updates.push(doc.ref.set({ roles }, { merge: true }));
    });

    await Promise.all(updates);

    console.log(
      `Role${newRoles.length > 1 ? 's' : ''} added to ${updates.length} user${
        updates.length !== 1 ? 's' : ''
      }.`
    );
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return error;
  }
};

addRoles().catch((e) => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Here's where you create the service account btw.
[image: Service account]